# Options for command java: Is it called --add-modules (plural) or --add-module (singular)?

Tags: java, jetty

Why is Jetty using the following peculiar `java` command in order to specify the modules which are to be installed?

```
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-module=server,http,deploy
```

According to the [java command specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) it must be called `--add-modules` but not `--add-module`. I don't get it. Is it an option Jetty invented for its own purposes?

Comment: Where did you find that command? According to [jetty's documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html#og-start-reference) the option is called `--add-modules`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, it is here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html

Comment: Looks like they're both valid. By the way, that's an option you pass to jetty, not to java. They can call it whatever they want.

Comment: However, it is by nature a java command and how is it possible to define new options? I understand that the java command allows system properties like -Dtype=customer but introducing complete new options? How does this work?

Comment: Whatever comes after the name of the jar will be passed to the jar, not to the `java` command, even stuff like `-Dtype=customer`. As per the link you gave that documents how to run java, the command line for a jar is `java [options] -jar jarfile [args ...]` where `[options]` *"Specifies command-line options separated by spaces. See Overview of Java Options for a description of available options."*, while `[args ...]` *"are passed as arguments to the main class"*

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, you are right because the regular java command options appear right after the java command and --add-module is an arg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html) it looks like they're both valid and acceptable for Jetty. It's unclear whether the `--add-module` form accepts more than one argument, but if in doubt I'd use `--add-modules` even to add a single module.

By the way, that's an option you pass to jetty, not to java. They can call it whatever they want.

As per the [java manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html), the command line to run a jar is

```
java [options] -jar jarfile [args ...]`
```

where `[options]`

> Specifies command-line options separated by spaces. See Overview of Java Options for a description of available options."

while `[args ...]`

> are passed as arguments to the main class